# Automate layer creation ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I was trying to build a function that automates the changing in some ggplot layers.
Specifically i wrote a function that should modify `axis.text` and `axis.title`.

```
axis_view_presentation<-function(plot,data,axis_title_x,axis_title_y,...)
{
 #browser()
  if(axis_title_x==TRUE & axis_title_y==TRUE )
  {
    plot+theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust=0.5,size=20,face="bold"),
      axis.text.x = element_text(size=18,hjust=1,...),
      axis.text.y = element_text(size=18,hjust=1,...),
      axis.title.x =element_text(size=18,...),
      axis.title.y = element_text(size=18,...))

  }

  if(axis_title_x==FALSE & axis_title_y==TRUE )
  {
    plot+theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust=0.5,size=20,face="bold"),
      axis.text.x = element_text(size=18,hjust=1,...),
      axis.text.y = element_text(size=18,hjust=1,...),
      axis.title.x =element_blank(),
      axis.title.y = element_text(size=18,...))
  }

  if(axis_title_x==TRUE & axis_title_y==FALSE )
  {
    plot+theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust=0.5,size=20,face="bold"),
      axis.text.x = element_text(size=18,hjust=1,...),
      axis.text.y = element_text(size=18,hjust=1,...),
      axis.title.y =element_blank(),
      axis.title.x = element_text(size=18,...))
  }

  if(axis_title_x==FALSE & axis_title_y==FALSE )
  {
    plot+theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust=0.5,size=20,face="bold"),
      axis.text.x = element_text(size=18,hjust=1,...),
      axis.text.y = element_text(size=18,hjust=1,...),
      axis.title.x =element_blank(),
      axis.title.y = element_blank())
  }

}
```

A reproducible example

```
data<-data.frame(x=rnorm(20),y=rnorm(20))
p<-ggplot(data=data,aes(x=x,y=y))+
        geom_point()
```

That returns this

[image]

If I call my function with

```
 p%>%axis_view_presentation(data=data,axis_title_x=TRUE,axis_title_y=FALSE)
```

it gives me the same plot displayed above

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return the plot

```
    axis_view_presentation<-function(plot,data,axis_title_x,axis_title_y,...)
{
  #browser()
  if(axis_title_x==TRUE & axis_title_y==TRUE )
  {
    plot_new <-  plot+theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust=0.5,size=20,face="bold"),
               axis.text.x = element_text(size=18,hjust=1,...),
               axis.text.y = element_text(size=18,hjust=1,...),
               axis.title.x =element_text(size=18,...),
               axis.title.y = element_text(size=18,...))

  }

  if(axis_title_x==FALSE & axis_title_y==TRUE )
  {
    plot_new <-  plot+theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust=0.5,size=20,face="bold"),
               axis.text.x = element_text(size=18,hjust=1,...),
               axis.text.y = element_text(size=18,hjust=1,...),
               axis.title.x =element_blank(),
               axis.title.y = element_text(size=18,...))
  }

  if(axis_title_x==TRUE & axis_title_y==FALSE )
  {
    plot_new <-  plot+theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust=0.5,size=20,face="bold"),
               axis.text.x = element_text(size=18,hjust=1,...),
               axis.text.y = element_text(size=18,hjust=1,...),
               axis.title.y =element_blank(),
               axis.title.x = element_text(size=18,...))
  }

  if(axis_title_x==FALSE & axis_title_y==FALSE )
  {
   plot_new <- plot+theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust=0.5,size=20,face="bold"),
               axis.text.x = element_text(size=18,hjust=1,...),
               axis.text.y = element_text(size=18,hjust=1,...),
               axis.title.x =element_blank(),
               axis.title.y = element_blank())
  }
  return(plot_new)
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks. I m wondering why this example from Rbloggers works :                                        add_line_points2 <- function(plot, df, ...) {
  plot +
    geom_line(aes(x = Time, y = weight, group = Chick), ..., data = df) +
    geom_point(aes(x = Time, y = weight), ..., data = df)
}
 
(plot4 <- ggplot() %>% add_line_points2(diet1)
   %>% add_line_points2(diet2, colour = "red"))

Comment: This might help 
https://www.datamentor.io/r-programming/return-function

Comment: when the function is simple enough (e.g. one operation), a return() isn't a must, you don't even have to assign the value to a variable, but in your case (a more complex function) you should at least assign it (what you want to output) to a variable name, and then the return statement is not obligatory but advised

Comment: Ok thanks. Reading your reference "If there are no explicit returns from a function, the value of the last evaluated expression is returned automatically in R." Probably we can say that the last evaluated expression in my code is often an if statement and so it returns nothing?

Comment: I got a great answer from a friend of mine: ........ it does not work because the function would evaluate the first if and see that the condition is false. then go to the second one, same thing. then it goes to the third one and evaluates as true, and changes the plot. then it goes to the fourth one, evals false and returns NULL. this is why you need to specifically return something.

Comment: Other option would be to use one if statement (i.e. if .... else if .... ) or you could add `return ()` in each if statement